# Rewrite rule to only rename one file in a directory- .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to rename just one file in a directory, and leave all the others as-is. I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule min.js min.php [L]
```

I want min.js to redirect to min.php, which it is doing fine. The problem is when I link to any other files in the directory, ALL the files redirect to min.php.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have other rules in this .htaccess also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You more than likely have other files in the directory that contain `min.js`. Because the rule does not open `^` and close `$`, the expression will match any file *containing* `min.js`. As such, try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^min.js$ min.php [L]
```